# Generating random IID numbers with variance 1/n

Tags: python, numpy, random, variance, iid

Here is the spec :

> A sufficient condition for correlation to decode convolution is that the elements of each
> vector (of dimension n) be independently and identically distributed with mean 0 and
> variance 1/n.

What I do is :

```
    stdev = np.sqrt(1/n) #var to std dev
    val = np.random.normal(loc=0,scale=stdev,size=n)
```

Are the generated numbers IID ?

Is variation => stdev logic correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy's random number generator uses the same distribution and will independently generate random numbers for n times, so the numbers are i.i.d. And standard deviation is square root of variance, so your logic is correct.